# How to implement Service workers with JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp, browser-cache, service-worker-events

My files structure is as below

- webapp

  - resources

    - service-worker.js
  - WEB-INF

    - views

      - app.jsp

Service worker registration code is inside app.jsp page. which is accessing the service-worker.js file.But as both service-worker.js and registration code has to be place in parallel, so Service worker is not working.